# Select specific titles based on friends' posts

Tags: php, mysql, filter, group-by

I have some tables.

**titles**

```
id| title

1 | Cars
2 | Computers
3 | Phones
4 | Tvs
```

**entry**

```
id | title_id | user_id | entry    | time
1  | 1        | 12      | entry-01 | 1
2  | 2        | 11      | entry-02 | 2
3  | 3        | 12      | entry-03 | 3
4  | 2        | 11      | entry-04 | 4
5  | 3        | 11      | entry-05 | 5
6  | 4        | 12      | entry-06 | 6
7  | 4        | 13      | entry-07 | 7
8  | 4        | 11      | entry-08 | 8
9  | 1        | 10      | entry-09 | 9
10 | 2        | 12      | entry-10 | 10
```

**users**

```
id | username 
10 | user-1
11 | user-2
12 | user-3
13 | user-4
```

**friends**

```
id | user_id | friend_id 
1  | 10      | 12
2  | 11      | 12
3  | 12      | 10
4  | 10      | 11
```

I need to filter titles based on friends' entries and sort the results by (entry.time) desc. And I also need to show friends name and count(entry) at the list.

Expected result filtered by user_id=10 is:

**result**

```
1 | Computers | user-3, user-2(2)
2 | Tvs       | user-2, user-3
3 | Phones    | user-2, user-3
4 | Cars      | user-3
```

any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a query in here somewhere? Also that result format is really going to be obnoxious to produce.

Comment: i do have a query but it does not work as expected :/

Comment: As I'm not psychic, and neither is anyone else here, can you please add it to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is complex, but if you get into the habit of breaking problems down into smaller pieces you will catch on pretty quickly. Why not start by getting all friends of user id 10? We can do so like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN user_id = 10 THEN friend_id
        WHEN friend_id = 10 THEN user_id END AS userFriends
FROM friends
GROUP BY userFriends
HAVING userFriends IS NOT NULL;
```

Notice the use of a case statement, because user_id 10 could be in either of the two columns. I use the GROUP BY in case the user/friend pair appears multiple times (like 10 and 12 for your example) and a check for not null to remove the rows that didn't match the case.

Now that you have those, you can join it with the entries and titles tables to get the information you're going to need. Just add in some aggregation to get the number of entries each user has for a title:

```
SELECT t.title, u.userName, COUNT(*) AS numEntries
FROM titles t
LEFT JOIN entry e ON e.title_id = t.id
JOIN users u ON u.id = e.user_id
JOIN(
  SELECT 
    CASE WHEN user_id = 10 THEN friend_id
    WHEN friend_id = 10 THEN user_id END AS userFriends
  FROM friends
  GROUP BY userFriends
  HAVING userFriends IS NOT NULL) f ON f.userFriends = u.id
GROUP BY t.title, u.userName;
```

Matching your format is going to be very tricky. Typically, you can use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to get a comma separated list, but you will get something like `user3, user2, user2` for your first list. To fix this, I recommend writing a CONCAT() in your select statement to modify the above query to get the number of entries to the side of each user. In addition, use another CASE statement so that this only happens when the COUNT(*) is greater than 1:

```
SELECT t.title, 
  CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN
    CONCAT(u.userName, ' (', COUNT(*), ')')
  ELSE
    u.userName
  END AS numEntries
FROM titles t
LEFT JOIN entry e ON e.title_id = t.id
JOIN users u ON u.id = e.user_id
JOIN(
  SELECT 
    CASE WHEN user_id = 10 THEN friend_id
    WHEN friend_id = 10 THEN user_id END AS userFriends
  FROM friends
  GROUP BY userFriends
  HAVING userFriends IS NOT NULL) f ON f.userFriends = u.id
GROUP BY t.title, u.userName;
```

And now, I would preform a GROUP_CONCAT() on that query:

```
SELECT tmp.title, GROUP_CONCAT(tmp.userEntries) AS friendEntries
FROM(
  SELECT t.title, 
    CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN
      CONCAT(u.userName, ' (', COUNT(*), ')')
    ELSE
      u.userName
    END AS userEntries
  FROM titles t
  LEFT JOIN entry e ON e.title_id = t.id
  JOIN users u ON u.id = e.user_id
  JOIN(
    SELECT 
      CASE WHEN user_id = 10 THEN friend_id
      WHEN friend_id = 10 THEN user_id END AS userFriends
    FROM friends
    GROUP BY userFriends
    HAVING userFriends IS NOT NULL) f ON f.userFriends = u.id
  GROUP BY t.title, u.userName) tmp
GROUP BY tmp.title;
```

I apologize for the lengthy response (though I wanted to be clear and cover it all). If you've made it to this point, you'll be happy to know that it works in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6816/11).

Comment: yes this works but it takes 4 queries. don't you think it is possible to handle it 1 or maybe 2 queries at least?

Comment: If your database is properly indexed this shouldn't run too slowly. However, I will tinker to see if I can make it smaller but it's unlikely.

Comment: this is pretty good already. id keys are indexed at the relevant tables.

Comment: It's hard to pull anything out. The outer most query is required to group_concat the rows into the format you want, the next one in gets the users and number of appropriate entries for each, and the inner subquery is required to get the friends of user 10 so I can't quite see how to pull that out. Unless you find this runs too slow or is too hard to maintain, I wouldn't fret.

Comment: btw, there is an issue. this query sorts alphabeticly. it should have been chronological due to time field of entry table.

Comment: @OzanÖzgür if that's true, your expected results are incorrect.